# Xcode 7 crashing due to (may be a bad) "Watch expression" and Expressions plist file is absent

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, xcode7

I am working on a C++ project.

I added a watch expression while the execution had paused at a breakpoint.

It crashed Xcode.

Now, when I try to break anywhere in that method, since Xcode somehow remembers the expression, it tries to evaluate it and crash again. Had it given me 5 full seconds, I could have deleted it. But until it's not in scope, it isn't showed. When it comes in scope, Xcode crashes!

As suggested on numerous pages, I went to the xcodeproject file, right-clicked it, selected "show package contents", and I was supposed to delete

**[my_workspace].xcworkspace/xcuserdata/[login_user_name].xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Expressions.xcexplist**

But the file is not there. There was another plist for breakpoints. I read it, and has no expressions in it. I deleted it anyway. Didn't help.

I am using Xcode 7.3.

I want to remove that expression from Watch list. I am ok with a solution deleting All of them I have added.

Am I looking at wrong (or obsolete) place?

How do I remove an expression from watch list of Xcode debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out.

Went to Window->Projects,
Selected my project, and
Deleted derived data.

That solved the issue.
Keeping it for the record, may be someone else can save some time :)